# how to check if user has write access to a database in java

Tags: java

I want to check if the user has write access permission to given database and server name using java.

I am using Sybase database

for example

server :ABC_server

db: xx_db

I want to check basically the user is in "read-write" group. if he is in that group, he will definitely have access to read and write permissions.

Comment: you can issue a query from java to check user rights on the database and tables

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking database permissions can begin from database/schema level permissions to specific table and column level select/insert/update permissions. Different databases have different levels. If you want to know whether a user has permission at any level you can do one of these:

1. Query the system tables where the database stores the permission data.
2. Try to run the operation. Operation error indicates that permission is not granted.

Typically system table access is limited to admin users only. Therefore No. 1 is not an option. Then you will be left with only No. 2. Try the operation on the database and table of your interest. If the operation fails you know the user has no permission. If the operation succeeds you may have to roll back the changes done if the operation was insert/update.

Comment: I can't check by doing operation one one table and confirm that is fine. I have an idea. updated my post